# Is okay to have mutiple models/classes for same entity (Different fields)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Some entities in my application are complex and have many fields that many times I don't need but sometimes I do. Many times in the front end I only see a couple of fields so I was wondering if it is correct to have several models defined for the same entity.
Simplified example:

```
class PersonModel {
   id
   name
   lastname
   country
}
class PersonModel {
   id
   name       
   dni
   lastname
   childs
   pets
   ...   
}
```

Comment: If you want to reuse members, then create a class that inherits the base class.

Comment: @John Sometimes i want differents fields. already edited my example.

Comment: Same entity you mentioned is database entity, I assume. In that case it is OK to have multiple model as per user interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

To give you the exact answer, we will need to know what kind of application you are making (ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web API) and if you are using the MVVM pattern.

Considering that you are making a Web API, I think you are referring to "Data Transfer Objects" or simply `DTO`.
DTOs allow you to serve data to the front-end. So yes it is totally fine to have multiple DTOs based off a single Business Entity or Model.

If you have multiple front-end "Views" that are based of the same Business Entity, it is recommended that you create multiple DTOs for those views, so that you dont have to expose any extra data to your front-end

Comment: Why does the application type matters?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should have different models. Those models have also different names by the purpose.

I try to keep my example simple and not go through every layer in the application. You mentioned front end so I use interface in my example. It really doesn’t matter what application type you have… every program has an interface. Some have a web interface and some use simple console interfaces.

Basic rule what I use is: `Don’t pass database model outside your app.`

It means that when you draw your interface, you want to map the database model (EF model in c# for example) to a more usable interface model. Depending on the application, I name these object by following way: **Responses, Views, ViewModels, etc.**

Those objects have a purpose and usually, you don’t want to expose your database model. Using specific models are easy. Just define the fields that you need and fill the object using database models.

Some benefits to using simpler models than complex database classes:

- Database framework is not leaking outside the application.
- You can use simpler field types… for example, it is much easier to print a string field than complex datatypes.
- Changes in database models don't break the front end, you have protected yourself from unexpected changes.

Of course, there are some cons also. You introduce new classes that sometimes can be hard to maintain. If so, then I usually use “mapping” framework to simplify field mapping. Anyway, the benefits are better when the application grows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach is good design. Having multiple classes that only contains a certain selection of attributes is not very maintainable. It's not very readable (difficult to understand). At least polymorphism would've been nice.

But I would encapsulate a selected set of attributes by using interfaces to segregate them. This way each interface can represent a role or scenario.

```
// Minimal reasonable set of attributes
interface IPerson 
{
   id
   name
   lastname
   country
}

// This interface extends IPerson
interface IPersonDetails : IPerson 
{
   dni
   childs
   pets
   ...   
}

// Maybe add some database related attributes like primaryKey
interfcae IPersonEntity : IPerson, IPersonDetails 
{
}


// A PersonModel is an implementation of all role interfaces
class PersonModel : IPersonEntity 
{
}
```

How is it used?

```
class Main 
{
   // The 'full' entity model e.g. fetched from database
   IPersonEntity completePerson = new PersonModel();

   // Here I only need the reduced set of attributes
   IPerson reducedPerson = completePerson;

   // This method only knows the reduced set of attributes
   public void SendLetterTo(IPerson person)
   {}

   // Use the above method which can only use name and address (IPerson members)
   SendLetterTo(completePerson);

   // Here I need only the details 
   IPersonDetails personDetails = completePerson;

   // Here I need the full set of attributes
   DeletePersonFromDatabase(completePerson);

   // Deletes a person from database. Needs to know all person attributes
   DeletePersonFromDatabase(IPersonEntity personToDelete) 
   {}
}
```